# code won't print back numSum as numSum = 2 points in an array

Tags: c++

trying to have this take inputs, create an array from numOne, the zero spot of the array is numTwo and it adds one to the value of the rest of the array positions until the array is filled, then it should print the array and the sum of positions [3] and [4] of the array.

```
    int arrayOperations(int numOne, int numTwo, int numThree,int numFour);

int main(){

int numOne;
int numTwo;
int numThree;
int numFour;


    cout<<"Enter a number 3 through 9"<<endl;
    cin>>numOne;
    cout<<"Now a number 5 through 17"<<endl;
    cin>>numTwo;

int arrayOperations(int numOne, int numTwo, int numThree,int numFour);




return 0;
}

int arrayOperations(int numOne, int numTwo, int numThree,int numFour){
int newArray[numOne];
int numSum;
    newArray[0]=numTwo;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOne; i++){
        newArray[i]=newArray[i-1]+1;
            cout<<newArray[i]<<endl;    
    }
numSum = newArray[3] + newArray[4]; 

return numSum;
}
```

Comment: You don't even call `arrayOperations`, so, why did you expect your code to print anything?

Comment: change `int arrayOperations(int numOne, int numTwo, int numThree,int numFour);` -> `arrayOperations(numOne, numTwo, numThree,numFour);`. The former is not a function call.

Comment: The mention of `arrayOperations` in `main` is just another **declaration**, just like the one at the top of the file. You have to **call** the function: `arrayOperations(numOne, numTwo, numThree, numFour);`. But don't be surprised if you still don't get any output; the code in `arrayOperations` has several errors in it.

Comment: Errors in the function `arrayOperations` - start `i` from `1` and not `0`. Starting from `0` will make your first iteration to be  `newArray[0]=newArray[-1]+1;`. which causes undefined behavior. Moreover, your `newArray` can have minimum size of `3`, so the line `numSum = newArray[3] + newArray[4]; ` can again cause undefined behavior.

Comment: My advice is to spend some time to learn how to use your debugger to single step through your code looking at your variables. As a programmer it is an essential tool that I still use regularly even after 30+ years of programming.

Comment: i see that now, thank you. i had to change the args to just the names also, instead of using the ints.

Comment: thank you all for the constructive feedback. this was my first question asked so now i have some tips to look at before i ask more questions. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The function call has a different syntax than the function declaration. Also you should start your for loop from 1 because the i-1 index will gives -1 which will return some garbage value. Here is the correct code..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int arrayOperations(int numOne, int numTwo, int numThree,int numFour);

int main() {

int numOne;
int numTwo;
int numThree;
int numFour;


cout<<"Enter a number 3 through 9"<<endl;
cin>>numOne;
cout<<"Now a number 5 through 17"<<endl;
cin>>numTwo;

cout<<arrayOperations(numOne,numTwo, numThree,numFour);




return 0;
}

int arrayOperations(int numOne, int numTwo, int numThree,int numFour) {
int newArray[numOne];
int numSum=0;
newArray[0]=numTwo;
for(int i = 1; i < numOne; i++) {
    newArray[i]=newArray[i-1]+1;
    cout<<newArray[i]<<endl;
}
numSum = newArray[3] + newArray[4];

return numSum;
}
```